# Populating a layout with another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have a customized `listView`. The list basically holds a layout (say L). This layout L is divided into two layouts L1 and L2, placed vertically. Now L1 has a `textfield` and L2 is empty. Now when a list item is clicked, the layout L2 corresponding to that `list item` should get populated with a third layout L3. I have read the suggestions which the forum itself provides, but none of them covers the layout inflation for a `list view` item type, please help.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could handle this: define your full L3 already in the beginning and set its `visibility` to `GONE`. When you want to display it set the `visibility` to `VISIBLE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of L3 is gone in L1 and inside onsetClickListener or onsetItemClickListener of L2 , you can set the visibity of L3 as visible.